# how to fetch the MySQL data and use it on the controller in CODEIGNITER

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

[image: Model and Controller Image]
I am facing the data from the database as an array and now I want to access the data in the same Controller method. Is it possible?
suppose my MODEL is (method name attendance)

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT emp_name FROM attendance WHERE id= '1' ");
        $result = $query->getResult('array');
```

My controller:

```
$data["emp_info"]=$this->userdata->attendance();
        return view("addleave_v",$data);
```

So in the controller, I have fetched the data and stored it on $data['emp_info'] it is a single element array. So I want to use the emp_name in the controller. How can I use it?  I tried `emp_info['emp_name], $data['emp_info']['emp_name']`
I have used an image attachment. Thanks

Comment: You are trying to show this in a view called addleave_v. So can you show the code for this view?

Comment: Yes, I can show the data on the view using <?=$emp_info['uiid'];?> but i want to use this value on the controller, not on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to see the library [Result Arrays](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays) and [Result Rows](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows).

Based on the data you provided (var_dump)

> array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["uiid"]=> string(2) "30"
> ["attendance_date"]=> string(10) "2021-03-09" ["emp_id"]=> string(1)
> "9" ["time_in"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["time_out"]=>
> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["comments"]=> string(14) "APPROVED
> LEAVE" ["overtime"]=> string(1) "0" ["status1"]=> string(1) "1"
> ["created_by"]=> string(0) "" ["total_time"]=> string(0) "" } }

1. Your array is structured as a *multi-element array*. You can view the current data using a loop (**foreach**) or refer to the first element of an array (in controller **$data["emp_info"][0]['emp_name']** or in view **$emp_info[0]['emp_name']**).
2. If you need a *single-element array*, use **getRowArray()** or **getRow('array')**. Then you will be able to use the variables as you first wanted.

- in controller **$data["emp_info"]['emp_name']**
- in view **$emp_info['emp_name]**

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you try the **print_r($emp_info);** command in your **view**(*addleave_v*). You will see what data structure has been assigned to the variable.

Comment: I already stated that getResult('array') So this is a nested array. By the way here is the var_dump data.
array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["uiid"]=> string(2) "30" ["attendance_date"]=> string(10) "2021-03-09" ["emp_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["time_in"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["time_out"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["comments"]=> string(14) "APPROVED LEAVE" ["overtime"]=> string(1) "0" ["status1"]=> string(1) "1" ["created_by"]=> string(0) "" ["total_time"]=> string(0) "" } }